# How can I split this in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing, split

I am trying to split something in PHP, and I can't get it to work.. Been trying for a while now, so thought I would ask here.

So lets say that I have multiple `<script> ... </script>` in my source code, then what can I do to split these  into a string. I'm trying with explode, but not working out as planned.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$script = explode('<script>',$data,1); 
echo htmlspecialchars($script[1]);
```

Tried that but it doesn't get any specific `<script>`.

Example script:

```
<script>
script here...
</script>

<script>
second script here...
</script>
```

So how will I go about getting the second script?

Sorry, I'm not the best at regex or parsing in PHP yet, and merry christmas to all of you! :)

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: $script = explode('<script>',$data,1);
echo htmlspecialchars($script[1]);

---- Tried that but it doesn't get any specific <script>

Comment: @Anders: What is the expected output?

Comment: Use a dom parser like `xpath` or `DOMDocument`, doing this with string functions or regex is kinda bad idea for reasons which can be googled

Comment: $Amal Murali: Just the input inside the <script> .. </script>.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Found one that worked for me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not parse HTML with string functions. Or regex, for that matter. the `<center>` cannot hold regexes and HTML. But that's a different story. Instead, use an html parser, like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)(Which, for some reason, is blocked by my high school's stupid firewall). Please correct me if I'm wrong, since I can't access the docs for it.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=str_get_html($text);
$scripts=$html->find("script");
foreach($scripts as $script){
    echo(htmlspecialchars($script));
}
```

Comment: It will be OK in my case, I just need to parse some JSON. But thank you! And have a nice christmas all of you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`loadHTML()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML string we want to strip
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// get all the script tags
$script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of string functions, I'd use a DOM Parser such as PHP's DOMDocument to extract the required data. Here's how you can do it:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
<script>
script here...
</script>

<script>
second script here...
</script>
TEXT;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Some explanation:

The text is loaded using [`loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method and then you use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method to get all the script tags. Now we use `item(1)` to specifically target the second `<script>` tag and then echo the [`nodeValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) of that node.

Output:

```
second script here...
```